# Null in group by?

Tags: sql

When I use this select I don't get the null camp grouped:

```
(SELECT Texto AS Tipo
 FROM TablaTodos)
UNION
(SELECT Gestiones.Tipo 
 FROM Gestiones
 group by Gestiones.Tipo);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can simply remove the GROUP BY here, UNION will take care of the removal of duplicates.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I've tried with group by and without group by and the NULL row is inserted in result list

Comment: With Sql Server: Go here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a245/1/0

Comment: Do you want NULL to be returned or should they be removed?

Comment: Can you give us some sample data (for both tables), and also wanted result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY` all columns (without using aggregate functions) is basically the same as `SELECT DISTINCT`.

`UNION` is the short form of `UNION DISTINCT`, i.e. duplicates are removed. So you can simply do:

```
(SELECT Texto AS Tipo
 FROM TablaTodos)
UNION
(SELECT Gestiones.Tipo 
 FROM Gestiones)
```

Comment: This seems like a comment rather than an answer. If I understand your answer correctly you are saying this should behave the same as the OP's query. Well if the OP's query doesn't behave as the OP wants, how can yours?

Comment: As I understand it OP is having GROUP BY problems with NULL (dbms bug?). Here I show how to write a query returning what OP wants, but without the GROUP BY. Isn't that a great answer?